# python loop not recognising beyond first JSON object

Tags: python, json, boto3

I have the following python code access s3 buckets and certificates. As you can see I have specified the MQTT_TOPIC I want the data/information to be sent to. This called later in the code

```
for uuid_index, uuid in enumerate(uuid_list): 
    for data in json_data:
        CLIENT_ID = "{client_id}".format(**data)
        MQTT_TOPIC = "{organisation}/{device_vendor}/{device_type}".format(**data)
        CERTIFICATION_PATH = "{organisation}/{uuid}".format(**data)
        result = client.list_objects(Bucket=cert_bucket, Prefix=CERTIFICATION_PATH)
        print('-------------------')
        print(result)
        print('-------------------')
```

My JSON file looks as follows - containing 5 uuids and 2 different organisations:

```
[    
    {
        "uuid": "1597c163-6fbf-4f46-8ff6-1e9eb4f07e34",
        "organisation": "port_36",
        "device_vendor": "bitgear",
        "device_type": "IO-Air",
        "client_id": "AQ_2"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "cde2107e-8736-47de-9e87-2033c3063589",
        "organisation": "hchjffsd2immvavb7jiqtedp",
        "device_vendor": "bitgear",
        "device_type": "IO-Air",
        "client_id": "IoT_Sim_1"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "7904f39f-97b0-4a6e-bd9d-fa692c40fe6f",
        "organisation": "hchjffsd2immvavb7jiqtedp",
        "device_vendor": "bitgear",
        "device_type": "IO-Air",
        "client_id": "AQ_1"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "c7880c2c-5386-44d4-ad0e-0002224d5f95",
        "organisation": "hchjffsd2immvavb7jiqtedp",
        "device_vendor": "bitgear",
        "device_type": "IO-Air",
        "client_id": "AQ_3"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "2be124d5-c069-493d-a44f-df4f363ce012",
        "organisation": "port_36",
        "device_vendor": "bitgear",
        "device_type": "IO-Air",
        "client_id": "AQ_4"
    }
]
```

I have ran my code in its entirety, and all 5 uuids are being read, but the information for each is being sent to the same MQTT Topic `port_36/bitgear/IO-Air` (the first JSON object read in). How can I get my loop to recognise the different uuids and their different organisations for publishing to MQTT topics?

edit - entire code in reply to comments below

```
# Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0
from awscrt import io, mqtt, auth, http
from awsiot import mqtt_connection_builder
import time as t
import json
import os, tempfile
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import random
import time



s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')
data_bucket = '3deo-sensor-data'
key = 'simulated/config/IoT-sim-config.json'
obj = s3.Object(data_bucket, key)
data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_data = json.loads(data)

uuid_list = [] #list containing the uuids 
for data in json_data:
    uuid_list.append(data["uuid"])


pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
RANGE = 2


def AQ_simulator(): #function to generate random data values for air quality for each uuid
    d = datetime.now().strftime(format)
    ts = time.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p')
    ts1 = time.mktime(ts)
    timestamp = int(ts1)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for uuid in uuid_list: 
        for x in range(RANGE):
            temp = pd.DataFrame({
                    'uuid': uuid,
                    'timestamp': str(timestamp),
                    'NO2 concentration': round(random.uniform(0, 0.017), 3),
                    'SO2 concentration': round(random.uniform(0, 0.022), 3),
                    'temperature': str(random.randint(3, 18)),
                    'relative humidity': str(random.randint(75, 90)),
                    'air pressure': str(random.randint(1011, 1016)),
                    'PM1.0 concentration': str(random.randint(5, 50)),
                    'PM2.5 concentration': str(random.randint(11, 26)),
                    'PM4 concentration': str(random.randint(7, 22)),
                    'PM10 concentration': str(random.randint(1, 20))[:4]}, index=[0],
                    columns = ['uuid', 'timestamp', 'NO2 concentration', 'SO2 concentration', 'temperature', 'relative humidity', 'air pressure', 'PM1.0 concentration', 'PM2.5 concentration', 'PM4 concentration', 'PM10 concentration'])
            df = pd.concat([df, temp])
    result = df.to_json(orient="records")
    parsed = json.loads(result)
    return parsed

MESSAGE = AQ_simulator()


if 'ENDPOINT' in os.environ:
    ENDPOINT = os.environ['ENDPOINT']
else:
    ENDPOINT = 'a3dd26595zqo4r-ats.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
if 'BUCKET ' in os.environ:
    BUCKET = os.environ['BUCKET']
else:
    BUCKET = '3deo-sensor-certificates'


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print("\nvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv")
    print(event)
    print("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n")
    

cert_bucket = '3deo-sensor-certificates'


for uuid_index, uuid in enumerate(uuid_list): for each uuid/json object extract the uuid, client_id, organisation, device vendor and device type data
    for data in json_data:
        uuid = "{uuid}".format(**data)
        CLIENT_ID = "{client_id}".format(**data)
        organisation = "{organisation}".format(**data)
        device_vendor = "{device_vendor}".format(**data)
        device_type = "{device_type}".format(**data)
        MQTT_TOPIC = "{organisation}/{device_vendor}/{device_type}".format(**data)
        CERTIFICATION_PATH = "{organisation}/{uuid}".format(**data) #AWS IoT topic that messages should be sent to
        result = client.list_objects(Bucket=cert_bucket, Prefix=CERTIFICATION_PATH)
        print('-------------------')
        print(result)
        print('-------------------')
            
        if 'Contents' in result: contents of s3 bucket based on above info
            list_out = []
            for key in result['Contents']:
                ## Return the files within the main /data directory - IGNORE any other sub directories.
                if not key['Key'].endswith('/'):
                    list_out.append(key['Key'])
            print(list_out)
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            os.chdir(tmpdir)
            for item in list_out:
                if 'certificate.pem.crt' in item:
                    cert_file = item.rsplit('/')[-1]  # split / grab the filename only
                    client.download_file(cert_bucket, item, cert_file)  # copy file to local storage
                    PATH_TO_CERT = os.getcwd() + '/' + cert_file  # configure path to file
                elif 'private.pem.key' in item:
                    key_file = item.rsplit('/')[-1]
                    client.download_file(cert_bucket, item, key_file)
                    PATH_TO_KEY = os.getcwd() + '/' + key_file
                elif 'AmazonRootCA1.pem' in item:
                    root_file = item.rsplit('/')[-1]
                    client.download_file(cert_bucket, item, root_file)
                    PATH_TO_ROOT = os.getcwd() + '/' + root_file
            print(PATH_TO_CERT)
            print(PATH_TO_KEY)
            print(PATH_TO_ROOT)
            # Spin up resources
            event_loop_group = io.EventLoopGroup(1)
            host_resolver = io.DefaultHostResolver(event_loop_group)
            client_bootstrap = io.ClientBootstrap(event_loop_group, host_resolver)
            mqtt_connection = mqtt_connection_builder.mtls_from_path(
                endpoint=ENDPOINT,
                cert_filepath=PATH_TO_CERT,
                pri_key_filepath=PATH_TO_KEY,
                client_bootstrap=client_bootstrap,
                ca_filepath=PATH_TO_ROOT,
                client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                clean_session=False,
                keep_alive_secs=6
            )
            print("Connecting to {} with client ID '{}'...".format(
                ENDPOINT, CLIENT_ID))
            # Make the connect() call
            connect_future = mqtt_connection.connect()
            # Future.result() waits until a result is available
            connect_future.result()
            print("Connected!")
            # Publish message to server desired number of times.
            print('Begin Publish')
    for data in MESSAGE[uuid_index * RANGE:(uuid_index+1) * RANGE]: #for each uuid, the generated messages in the very first loop should be published based on the MQTT_topic derived from each uuids info
        mqtt_connection.publish(topic=MQTT_TOPIC, payload=json.dumps(data), qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        print("Published: '" + json.dumps(data) + "' to the topic: " + MQTT_TOPIC)
        t.sleep(3)
print('Publish End')
disconnect_future = mqtt_connection.disconnect()
disconnect_future.result()
```

Comment: where is the push to the MQTT topic occuring? its not in your sample code?

Comment: It is later in the code - included now. The code is over 180 lines long so I have only included a snippet

Comment: the key thing is if `MQTT_TOPIC` is in the  `for data in json_data:` loop?  most likely that  `MQTT_TOPIC`  is set to the last value for the last item in the loop.

Comment: @Nath even if ```MQTT_TOPIC``` is placed outside of the loop, the data is always printed to the same MQTT topic

Comment: That's the point. After the loop, `MQTT_TOPIC` contains the value from the last iteration.

Comment: All the variables that are created from `**data` must be used within the loop so they have the values for that iteration.

Comment: I have tried including ```device_type``` etc in the loop but nothing seems to be making a difference

Comment: The for loop which publishes to the MQTT topic is also within the ```for data in json_data``` loop

Comment: Please post the whole loop so we can see how everything is related.

Comment: @Barmar please now find the entire code in the edits

Comment: The `for data in MESSAGE[uuid_index * RANGE:(uuid_index+1) * RANGE]:` loop is not inside `for data in json_data:`. So it just uses the last value of `MQTT_TOPIC`

Comment: Including it in the loop, I am getting all of the uuids published to both organisation topics. I was expecting them to parse out based on their organisation to the correct topic

Comment: Can you simplify this? There's so many loops and variables, I can't figure out what should be sent where. Can you add what messages you expect to be sent in each loop iteration?

Comment: I have added in comments! Essentially, the final result should be the simulated data for each uuid which was created in the very first loop, sent to each of the IoT Topics that have been derived based on the other information contained for that uuid